# Convert MMS streaming to any Android format

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, vlc

I have the following stream mms://77.238.11.5:8080, you can access it using Windows Mediaplayer.

I don't find any solution to view it on Android devices using MediaPlayer or VideoView, so my idea is to convert is using VLC or FFMPEG to a different format like MP4 or else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffmpeg to convert the stream to a file:

```
ffmpeg -i "mmsh://77.238.11.5:8080/" output.mp4
```

Option `-t duration` limits the length of the video, if needed.

Comment: but this convert the stream in file, I need to convert the MMS stream to a stream good for android, like HTTP progressive or RTP.

Answer (score 0):

They say that [VPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t) can play such streams.

Comment: I am not looking for a player, but for conversion help.